# ImageMagick resize without interpolation

Tags: resize, imagemagick

I have a small pixel map [image: original] and want to resize it for better readability.

Using `mogrify -resize 1600%` I get an interpolated image: [image: wrong].

What I'm trying to get is this: [image: right].

Can this be done by ImageMagick or any other open source command line tool?

Comment: @Danack: I did so and couldn't find an answer [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize). Otherwise I wouldn't have asked the question. Obviously I missed something. Maybe you could direct me to the relevant section in the documentation.

Comment: Use -scale rather than -resize or see -magnify at https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#scale and https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#magnify

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I finally found the solution: using `-scale` instead of `-resize` does the trick. It is 'hidden' under the heading [Scale - Minify with pixel averaging](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#scale), therefore I overlooked it at first, searching for *magnification* instead of *minification*.

Comment: its still interpolating for me, please include your command line next time...

Comment: @franck: `mogrify.exe -scale 1600% utRmU.png`

Comment: This didn't work for me on ImageMagick 7.1.1-21 on Mac, but the solution below with `-interpolate Integer` did

Comment: @TajhTaylor: this is strange, it works for me on `ImageMagick 7.1.1-24 Q16-HDRI x86_64 21856` on Linux. Please note that `mogrify` overwrites the original image, whereas `convert` writes to a different image file.

Comment: just to be clear - the command would be `mogrify -scale 1600% utRmU.png` **or** `convert utRmU.png -scale 1600% output.png`

Answer (score 13):

This worked for me:

```
convert input.png -interpolate Integer -filter point -resize "10000%" output.png
```

Explanation:

- Interpolation method "Integer" just picks a nearest value.
- Filter 'point' is also necessary, but I do not know why.

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me but this one does, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`display -sample 400%` worked for me.

"Change the image size simply by directly sampling the pixels original from the image. When magnifying, pixels are replicated in blocks. When minifying, pixels are sub-sampled (i.e., some rows and columns are skipped over)."

https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#sample

Answer (score 0):

To keep the original values of the input image and avoid any blend or bluriness, you can use `-interpolate nearest-neighbor` or `-interpolate integer`.

It only works along `-interpolative-resize`. Be aware that `-resize` does not work correctly with `-interpolate`. You can check [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#interpolative-resize) on the imagemagick docs.

e.g.

```
convert input.png -interpolate nearest-neighbor -interpolative-resize 1600% output.png
```